# Remove text indentation from select (Windows)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, native

I need a cross-browser solution to remove padding/text indentation of native select fields. Using `padding: 0` doesn't seem to remove it entirely.

Here's a screenshot of Chrome, with no text space on the left side:

[image: Chrome]

And here's a screenshot of Firefox, which has some text space on the left side:

[image: Firefox]

However, it should also remove the padding in e.g. Edge/IE11/Safari, etc. So it shouldn't be a Firefox only solution, rather a cross-browser solution.

Here's the code:

```css
select {
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

option {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/cbkopypv/1/

Comment: I see no difference between chrome and firefox with your example.  I'm not sure if it's what you're getting at, but try `* {padding:0; margin:0;}` to see if that gets you closer

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. If you can't see a difference then please open the image in e.g. Adobe Photoshop and you'll see that there are some px between the red background and the beginning of the text.

Comment: Ah I apologize. I see this issue now.  I removed the appearance:0 line and it added the small space between the T and the left side of the box back for chrome.  so am i correct in assuming that the appearance that you're wanting to achieve just needs to be consistent or do you need both of them to remove that space and look like chrome does now?

Comment: This seems to have some relevant information here: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

Comment: Yes, it needs to be consistent. The spacing should be removed in all others, like Chrome does. The link doesn't provide helpful information for me.

Comment: The Firefox fix is text-indent: -2px;.  Doesn't work on IE11.

Comment: See this [Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare) it might shed some light

Comment: Thanks, the link is interestingly but unfortunately, it doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a combination of some answers, comments and my own IE11 hack. I've tested it in IE11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox (Windows) and Safari 10 (macOS) and it works:

```css
.select-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

select {
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

option {
  padding: 0;
}


/* Firefox: */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  select {
    text-indent: -2px;
  }
}


/* Edge: */

@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  select {
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    margin-left: -4px;
  }
}


/* IE11: */

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  select {
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    margin-left: -3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="select-container">
  <select>
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cbkopypv/13/

We can't use the `margin` hack of Edge & IE11 for Firefox too, as it would cause the negative margin on the dropdown too. And we can't use the `text-indent` hack of Firefox in IE11 and Edge as it won't work.

Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the cleanest solution, but it works:

In addition to reseting the padding to 0, you can use the `text-indent` property and set different values for different browsers.

Looks like Safari and Chrome are good but Firefox and Edge are off by 2px, so you can shift them to the left by 2px in FF and IE only like so:

```
// firefox
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  select {
    text-indent: -2px
  }
}

// Edge
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  select {
    text-indent: -2px
  }
}
```

Those covers the major browser, check out [browserhacks.com](http://browserhacks.com/) if you think you'll need to target other browsers, devices, etc..

Hope that helps.

---

according to [browserhacks.com](http://browserhacks.com/) looks like another way of targeting IE/Edge ≥ 10 is `_:-ms-input-placeholder, :root .selector`

so you could add:

```
_:-ms-input-placeholder, :root select {
    text-indent:-2px
}
```

That seems to be working for me, Hope that works now for you too.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbkopypv/5/)

[fiddle with new IE updates](https://jsfiddle.net/cbkopypv/11/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A solution like that would be fine. However, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me in Edge nor IE11, see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGqPu.png

Comment: Updated the answer with another IE support hack I found on that browserhacks.com (selector, { property:value }

Comment: Negative text-indent works for Firefox. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat of a workaround and requires conditionals based on the browser. I find it unlikely that a true cross-browser solution is available.

Place the select inside a container element. Give that container an `overflow` of `hidden` and displace the `select` some pixels to the left. This would require you to be able to run slightly different CSS for IE/Edge (both work the same), Firefox and Chrome (which works with your original code).

The following works for both IE11 and Edge:

```css
select {
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

option {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select>
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

For Firefox, use `margin-left: -4px`

[Here's the fiddle for IE/Edge](https://jsfiddle.net/ro4uz2h7/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this approach would cause an overflow of option elements, as this screenshot demonstrates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jATA.png

Comment: @dude As far as I see this works OK in IE/Edge. Combine this answer with browser hacks from Sammy's answer and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This extra whitespace in firefox is added by the rendering engine of browser. Form element rendering is inconsistent across browsers, and in this case is not determined by CSS.

This might help :

[article from Mozilla explaining some ways to mitigate select box incosistency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare)

[Smashing Magazine(It's about styling form elements)](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/css-form-elements-problem/)

Comment: That's not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This and a whole bunch of other browser inconsistencies can be dealt with by using a 'css reset' file. One of the most popular, and the one I use on all of my projects is 'normalize.css':
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

This small amount of additional css ensures that all browsers render content the same (as well as can be acheived, at least).

What this will do to solve the problem in your specific case is use normalize's `<select>` tag rules to ensure that the padding, line-height, indenting (etc..) is set to appear consistently across all browsers. Then when you subsequently over-rule it with your own css styles - in this case: 
`padding:0; margin:0;`
it will appear that way across all targeted browsers.

I hope this helps. Normalize.css is one of those tools I wished I'd discovered earlier when I first found out about it. It will also solve layout problems you have not encountered yet, before you have them.